# Scraping html page using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

```
<?php 
    $contents = file_get_contents('link here');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($contents);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $xquery = '//tr[td[a]]';           
    $links = $xpath->query($xquery);   
    foreach ($links as $el) {
        $string = ($doc->saveHTML($el));
        preg_match('/<a class="LN" href=".*" onclick=".*">(.*)<\/a>/i', $string, $name); 
        preg_match('/<td align="center">.*\s*<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>/i', $string, $locations);
        echo strip_tags($name[1]).' '.strip_tags($locations[1]);
    } 
?>
```

the value of my $string is

```
  <tr>
<td>
1.
 </td>
<td>
<a class="LN" href="" onclick="">
<b>Aaberg, Aaron E</b></a>
</td>
<td align="center">
54 
</td>
<td><a href="">Anchorage, AK</a><br />
<a href="">Nondalton, AK</a><br />
</td>
<td> </td><td><a href="">
                    View Details
                  </a></td></tr>
```

Why i can't get my $location[i]?

Comment: you are already using XPath, why don't you let XPath do all the work? You probably don't need xpath+regex mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('http://....');

$pattern =
'@' . 
'<td>\s*+' .
'(?P<no>\d+)\.\s*+' .
'</td>\s*+' .
'<td>\s*+' .
'<a class="LN" href="[^"]*+" onclick="[^"]*+">\s*+' .
'<b>(?P<name>[^<]*+)</b>\s*+' .
'</a>\s*+' .
'</td>\s*+' .
'<td align="center">[^<]*+</td>\s*+' .
'<td>\s*+' .
'(?P<locations>(?:<a href="[^"]*+">[^<]*+</a><br />\s*+)++)' .
'</td>' .
'@'
;

$results = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $i => $match) {
    preg_match_all('@<a href="[^"]*+">([^<]*+)</a>@', $match['locations'], $locations);
    $results[$i]['no'] = $match['no'];
    $results[$i]['name'] = $match['name'];
    $results[$i]['locations'] = $locations[1];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
preg_match('/<td align="center">.*\s*<\/td>\s*<td>(.*)<\/td>/i', $string, $locations);
```

you can use

```
preg_match('/<a href="">(.+)<\/a><br \/>/i', $string, $locations)
```